# PHP abstract method with unknown number of arguments

Tags: php, abstract-class

I have:

- *abstract class Car* with an abstract method called *drive()*.

I have two classes which extend *Car* :

1. Manual_Car
2. Automatic_car

My problem is the method *drive()* has different number of arguments in this two cases.

This is the code :

```
abstract class Car{
    abstract public function drive( //variable number of args );
}

class Manual_Car extends Car{
   public function drive( $speed, $gearbox){
      ...
   }
}

class Automatic_Car extends Car{
   public function drive( $speed ){
      ...
   }
}
```

How can I declare my abstract class with an unknown number of arguments?

Comment: might be worth pointing out that every car needs a gearbox to run, so adding a private property `gearbox` as an instance of another type `Gearbox` to your abstract class and letting each car access it own gearbox via `$this->gearbox` might be a better solution.

Comment: Classes that extend an abstract should be substituteable. I.e., the code calling `drive()` shouldn't have to know it has to behave differently based on what type of object is instantiated. Rather than violate the signature of the inherited method, you'd be better off creating `Automatic` and `Manual` objects, and then inject them into your car object: `$car = new Car(new Gearbox\Manual());` Then, the code that behaves differently based on gearbox is in the gearbox classes, not the car class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !
Thanks to @Alex Howansky.

> Try to declare abstract class with unknown number of arguments is not the best practice because it makes a case of **signature violation**.

**Best Practice**

> All extra argument like `$gearbox` should be a **class parameter**.

**Solution code in my example :**

```
abstract class Car{

    protected $arg1, $arg2;

    public function __construct( $arg1, $arg2 ){
         $this->arg1 = $arg1;
         $this->arg2 = $arg2;
    }
    abstract public function drive( $speed );
}

class Manual_Car extends Car{

   protected $gearbox;

   public function __construct( $arg1, $arg2, $gearbox ){
         parent::__construct( $arg1, $arg2 );
         $this->gearbox = $gearbox;
    }

   public function drive( $speed ){
      ...
      //use $this->gearbox here 
   }
}

class Automatic_Car extends Car{
   public function drive( $speed ){
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP allows variable length arguments:

```
abstract class Car {
  abstract public function drive(...$args);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

edit:

Looks like PHP doesn't let you do this... shame. The above code errors. `varargs` seems to collect extra args into an array rather than just accept more arguments (or signal to the runtime that this `abstract` method accepts 0 or many arguments)

I did, however, get it working by getting rid of the `abstract` class

```
class Car {
  public function drive(...$args) { 
    throw new Exception("not implemented"); 
  }
}

class AutomaticCar extends Car {
  public function drive($speed, $gearbox) {
    echo $speed;
  }
}
```

the above will *warn* but not error. it's not perfect by *any* means - the onus is left to the implementer to actually figure out that `drive` is a required override, but it works.

```
$x = new AutomaticCar();
$x->drive(10, null); // null b/c I have no idea what you're doing

> 10
```

The warning is

```
PHP Warning:  Declaration of AutomaticCar::drive($speed, $gearbox) should be compatible with Car::drive(...$args)
```

but... and I'm not saying this is a good idea ...you can silence warnings.

Comment: Should mention this is `PHP 5.6+`

Comment: I tried this, but My IDE still show me an error of compatibily. My php version is 5.6.25, so I don't understand.

Comment: Which IDE you using

Comment: @AamirR PHPStorm

Comment: @Aamir Thanks but I know how to change my php version in PHPStorm, it's not the problem. I still have 5.6.25 and if I switch to 7.0, the error continue.

Comment: @Tyler Sebastien, Did you test the rest of the code ? For me there are errors for each _drive()_ function even if `...$args` in the abstract one does not get error.

Comment: I'm also using PHPStorm (v2017.2.4), and the code above works fine when the settings are set to v5.6+. When I drop it to 5.3, I get an error and tooltip saying `Variadic functions are available in 5.6` so @J.BizMai seems to be correct in my case

Comment: In netbeans I see error only if I reduce to PHP 5.5, otherwise works fine, never used PHPStorm but best of luck :)

Comment: @Tyler Sebastien. Thank you very much. Yes, in PHP 5.6+, with the `abstract` word, that does not work. I don't find the rignt solution for the moment but it is on the way...

Answer (score -2):

Did you try:

abstract public function drive( $speed, $gearBox = null);

If you have only two options, why would you want to use unknown number of arguments?

Comment: This is not an unknown number of arguments

Comment: that is true, but in his code he has only 2 options, so why use an unknown number of arguments?